# LCD display is garbled in between operations on STM32

Tags: microcontroller, stm32, lcd

I'm using a 16x2 LCD for a project on STM32F030R8. I wrote a library for interfacing and everything was working fine until recently. It displays garbled junk values in between operations, especially when I press a button and it has to change DRAM contents. It somehow started when my code size grew a lot or when I increased the MCU clock to 48 MHz. So far I'm clueless about what's causing this. It displays wrong characters on initialization after power down too.

EDIT: On my board, there is an interrupt service to update seven segment displays every 10 ms. Turning that off solves the problem. It might be that the interrupt is getting called in between LCD updates. Any idea how to solve this?

Comment: How are you interfacing to the LCD? SPI? I2C?

Comment: Nah, just vanilla GPIO.

Comment: I have to assume you mean a HD44780 compatible display? Post the code and schematics or we have little to work with.

Comment: Yes, that is so.

Comment: With no code, and no schematic we're clueless too about why it doesn't work. How would you answer this question if someone asked it to you?

Comment: "It somehow started when my code size grew a lot or when I ..." - That's a good one X-D

Comment: The timing for the HD44780 is not critical because the interface is synchronous (clocked by the ENABLE singal). But make sure you're not clocking out data too fast now that you increased the CPU clock (EN must be below 1MHz, and check the busy flag). Then make sure your ISR does not corrupt any data required for the display routines.

Comment: Does your stack overflow with real-time IRQ’s?

Comment: Try simplifying the situation and eliminating complications, especially your changes.  This is a great reason to use a version control system, as you can go back to an earlier version of your program and see if that still works.  If a scope is available check that the signals match the design intent, and look for anything spurious in between intentional operations.

Answer (score 1):

If your 10ms refresh rate isn't critical, maybe disable the timer at the start of the LCD update routine and restart it after the LCD is updated? I'm sure the LCD finishes quickly enough that it won't make a noticeable difference, depending on how much of the LCD you need to update.

Answer (score 0):

You say you upped the clock to 48MHz. Were you implementing any delays in your library? Some LCDs are quite slow and have minimum time requirements for some signal transitions.

Modifying the clock speed, especially increasing it, would likely have made those delays shorter and maybe now they are out of spec.

Code size probably has very little to do with it. Check the datasheet and make sure you are still within spec for your signals.

Comment: I don't think so. STM's HAL_Delay is pretty much clock-independent and besides I'm using large delays anyway.